# File not run in search.php

Tags: php, syntax-error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ')' in
>   /wp-content/themes/dream/search.php on line 75

```
if (!empty($available['from'] && $available['to']) && ($theDate > $availableFrom) && ($theDate < $availableTo)) { ?>
```

Comment: Always check the number of open and closed brackets when having problems with grouping logical conditions like this.

Comment: Missing a closing bracket in `!empty($available['from']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (!empty($available['from']) && !empty($available['to']) && ($theDate > $availableFrom) && ($theDate < $availableTo)) { ?>
```

Comment: In change this then go to line 109

<?php if(!empty($runningTime || $age)){ ?>

Comment: empty will accept only single variable for this you have to code : <?php if(!empty($runningTime) || !empty($age)){ ?>